# InvalidRequest error when trying to programmatically add permissions to a Drive item using GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using GraphServiceClient to programmatically add permissions to a Drive item in a SharePoint site. Here's the code I'm using:

```cs
client.Sites[siteId].Drive.Items[itemId].Permissions.Request().AddAsync(permissions);
```

I've verified that my client object has all the necessary permissions to modify the permissions on the Drive item. However, when I run this code, I receive an "invalidRequest" error. I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? What could be causing the "invalidRequest" error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) and it provides the code sample to add permissions to a Drive Item. Hope this helps. Best Wishes.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Drives.Item.Items.Item.Invite.InvitePostRequestBody
{
    Recipients = new List<DriveRecipient>
    {
        new DriveRecipient
        {
            Email = "ryan@contoso.com",
        },
    },
    Message = "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
    RequireSignIn = true,
    SendInvitation = true,
    Roles = new List<string>
    {
        "write",
    },
    Password = "password123",
    ExpirationDateTime = "2018-07-15T14:00:00.000Z",
};
var result = await graphClient.Drives["{drive-id}"].Items["{driveItem-id}"].Invite.PostAsync(requestBody);
```